# How do I place a div on top of another div?

Tags: html, css

I'm basically looking to have a centered image (the "drob" div) in the forefront at all times with the other divs sitting behind it should they overlap.

And here's the code:

```
body {
background-image:url('background.jpg');
}

#container {
width: 1040px;
height: 768px;
margin: 0 0 0 75px;
}


#navbar {
float: right;
height: auto;
width: 150px;
margin: 0 0 0 10px;
color: #FF0;
list-style: none;

}


#note {
width: auto;
height: auto;
float: left;
margin: 20px 0 0 -110px;

}


#drob {
height: auto;
width: auto;
float: left;
margin: 50px 0 0 -20px;

}


#gallery {
float: left;
width: 675px;
height: auto;
margin: -125px 0 0 -20px;

}


#gallery img {
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 5px;  

}


#video {
height: auto;
width: auto;
float: left;
margin: 150px 0 0 -20px;

}


<div id="container">
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Denard</li>
        <li>Stats</li>
        <li>Media</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="video">
<iframe width="450" height="265" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZmmCAI8U_Vc" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="drob">
<img src="images/drob.png" height="560" width="404" alt="Denard Robinson" />
</div>
<div id="note">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/note.png" height="464" width="331" alt="note" /></a>
</div>
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="denard1.jpg" height="145" width="215" alt="denard1" />
    <img src="denard2.jpg" height="145" width="215" alt="denard2" />
    <img src="denard3.jpg" height="145" width="215" alt="denard3" />
</div>

</div>    


</body>
```

Comment: If I read your question right you want #drop to be the main image then images within #gallery to be behind #drop? 

Can you please supply an image of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to set the z-index of your overlapping divs.

The div with the lower z-index will be behind the div with the higher index.

You can find out more about z-index at http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index

Answer (score 0):

As long as you dont have any select iframes you can put things on top just by adding a z-index.   But in thi scase, you have iframe..   so, try maybe using using absolute positioning to put one on top of the other.  would be something like:

```
#drob {
height: auto;
width: auto;
float: left;
margin: 50px 0 0 -20px;
position: absolute;
}
```

or maybe try both, z-index and position... since I think z-index works on positioned elemnts :

```
#drob {
height: auto;
width: auto;
float: left;
margin: 50px 0 0 -20px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
}
```

Maybe it would work